# empty string return statement in method, is this just for a nominal purpose or can this be improved?

Tags: java, string, return

This code removes the first "abc" which is in the string argument and returns the resultant string.

I'm just confused because I'm just returning an empty string because I wrote `String` instead of `void`. I would have used `System.out.println();` along with `break;` if I wrote `void` but I just didn't because I used it in an exercise and it said bad code(even though the results are same). Would be glad if you have any opinions.
This is my code below;

```
public static String abc(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < str.length()-2) {
        if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("abc")) {
            return str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+3);
        } else {
            if (i == str.length()-3) {
                return str;
            }
        } i++;
    } return "";
```

Comment: the codes have too many bugs. 1) if str is null the str.length() causes an exception. 2) If i+3 is bigger than str.length() you get boundary exception. 3) if str.length() -2 is negative your loop loops forever.

Comment: This code will not even compile. You have a return statement outside of the method...

Comment: A method with a specified return type must return something no matter what path is taken through the code and since you might not enter the while loop you need to handle that situation as well and return something. Although I would have returned `str` and not ""

Comment: @Voodoo         Yes the null exception is there. but `i+3` wont be greater than `str.length()` because `while(i < str.length()-2)` the compiler checks until `i+2` only(excluding `i+3`). min value `str.length()-2` can be is -2. then the loop wont start and will return the `""` empty string. i should change that to `return str` @Joakim Danielson

Comment: @Bradley           there is a `}` i didn't include at the end of the code, sorryy.

Answer (score 0):

For information on manipulating strings see the Java String API:https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html

You could achieve the same with much less code:

```
public static String abc(String str) {

    return (str.contains("abc")) ? str.replaceFirst("abc", "") : str ;

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JoakimDanielson , However I disagree. The answer provides a resource for Zaid to look over to further his knowledge on Strings. Also the answer is a much slicker way to achieve what Zaid was attempting. Time to move on. Thank-you.

Comment: Yes I agree to some extent but my point is that OP is asking about how to handle `return` rather than how to improve the string handling